Given a matrix $A$ over $F_2[x_1,...,x_n]$ where each entry of $A$ is linear, find the point $x \in F_2^n $ so that $A$ evaluated at $x$ has min rank
Given a matrix $A$ over $F_2[x_1,....,x_n]$ where each entry of $A$ is a linear combination of $x_1,...,x_n$. We say that $A$ evaluated at $x \in F_2^n$ is the matrix over $F_2$ obtained by setting $x_i = x[i]$.
To give an example, consider $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 + x_2 & x_1+x_3 \\
x_2 & x_1+x_2+x_3
\end{pmatrix} $$
and A evaluted at $x=(1,0,1)$ is matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 $$
I want to find the point $x \in F_2^n \backslash 0 $ which minimizes the rank. I am interested in anything related to this problem, and any algorithm to do this more efficient than the brute force approch.

The obvious answer would be to just set every one of $x_1,x_2....$ to be zero...

Hey, i forgot to say that we can not pick the point 0. Added it to the question now.

@Sander Alternately, you could allow the entries of the matrix to have constant terms. I suspect that that will ultimately yield the same problem (although I'm not 100% sure). And the problem itself feels SAT-adjacent, so it's possible it's NP complete.
